# mask-image: radial-gradient() no funciona en Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css

Tengo la siguiente línea de código css que funciona en Chrome pero no el Mozilla.

```
mask-image: radial-gradient(ellipse 20px 20px at 50% 50%, black 40%, transparent 50%);
```

De antemano muchas gracias!.[image: Aquí un ejemplo de cómo funciona en Chrome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la documentación de esta sentencia se explica que firefox no maneja soporte para esta instrucción. [-webkit-mask-image-](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-image)

Comment: Es una lástima veo que sólo funciona con -webkit-, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que poner los prefijos para cada navegador espero esto sea lo que buscas

```
#grad {
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(red, green, blue); /* Safari 5.1- 6.0 */
 background: -o-radial-gradient(red, green, blue); /* Opera 11.6-12.0 */
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(red, green, blue); /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
 background: radial-gradient(red, green, blue); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

En el caso de que quieras que funcione en `Firefox` :

```
mask-image: -moz-radial-gradient(ellipse 20px 20px at 50% 50%, black 40%, 
 transparent 50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado esta pagina que tal vez pueda servirte.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask